# How to visualize a calendar with a vast amount of recurring events?

Tags: research, calendar

Many of the events are recurring daily or weekly but are only interesting to the user once.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Why are the events only interesting once? Do these events block out specific times of day (e.g. staff meeting Tuesdays 10-11am) or do they just need to be noted (e.g. Wednesday garbage collection)?

Comment: Just noted. It´s more a situation where there are som courses that are given on a daily basis or a few times a week and a lot of events are weekly. If you dont like something or have already attended it, it should still be visible but not hinder you from finding something you like or something new. I realize this is somewhat complicated to describe/answer in text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This spiral plot example is used for historical data, but the general idea might be adaptable..?

[image]

Comment: That is not unlike a calendar at all. With certain limitations it could work. Looks a bit like this: http://cl.ly/3G1W003b1v2K0n0Z2G1X

Answer (score 1):

Idea:
Small Icons (e.g. color+symbol) for these events, that are listed either in a separate list outside of the calendar, or within the calendar, but only once.

Mousing over one of the icons could highlight all icons of the same event, so that the repetition pattern can be spotted easily.

Comment: Thanks. That solution with an addition of the possibility to filter/refine events shown could work. I was also thinking of displaying the calendar on a timeline and presenting the recurring events bellow the timeline and singular/more interesting events above.

Comment: Was going to suggest this, good idea!

Answer (score 1):

suggestion, a button that 'fades' the recurring appointments to a light pastel (or similar) and keeps the unique appointments with full saturation.  All hover and click functionality should remain, but a 'highlight only unique appointments' button would be a good idea (though I'd hope you find a smaller name/description).